# SQlite compare dates without timestamp

Tags: sql, sqlite

In SQLite, how to compare date without passing timestamp?

The date format is `2018-03-18 08:24:46.101655+00` and I want to compare against only date part as `2018-03-18`.

I have tried as where `mydate='2018-03-18'` but that didn't return any records.

Similarly, tried `Date(mydate)='2018-03-18'` but that didn't help either.

How can I compare dates ignoring the timestamp part?

Answer (score 1):

```
select * from mytable
where strftime('%Y-%m-%d', mydate) = '2018-03-18'
```

Answer (score 1):

This is not one of the supported [date formats](http://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html#datetime).

To extract the date part from the string, use [substr()](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_corefunc.html#substr):

```
... WHERE substr(mydate, 1, 10) = '2018-03-18'
```

It might be a better idea to store dates in a correct format in the database to begin with.

Answer (score 1):

It is looking that there is problem with date format.
Sqlite doesn't understand data like '+00' in date.
So date() and strftime() will not work here if data type is 'timestamp with time zone'.
Try by using like clause.

Answer (score 0):

Try using strftime

```
SELECT strftime('%Y %m %d', 'columnName');
```

you can find it here [strftime.php](https://www.techonthenet.com/sqlite/functions/strftime.php)